# DotCMS install to existing tomcat errors

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, dotcms

I'm currently trying to install dotCMS to an existing tomcat installation. I've extracted the war and dropped it into `/webapps/ROOT` in tomcat. I've edited the `ROOT.xml` file to point to the MySQL database I have set up called dotcms. When starting tomcat, the database is created by dotCMS and this appears fine. When trying to login however, I am getting the following error:

```
24-Nov-2011 10:46:40 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: 
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@1af33d6
 org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I can only assume it is missing a jar or not looking in the correct place?

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this one for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Managed to fix it by removing a huge chunk of the web.xml that was referencing the JSPs. Seems to work now!

Comment: I just had the same issue, but can't for the life of me figure out **why** a huge chunk referencing JSPs suddenly appeared in the first place (weeks after deploying and making changes). It says it was generated by Tomcat, but it's totally WTF and continues to support my poor opinion of the Java/Eclipse stack—things break at random, without even touching them!